# Jekyll - How to change default layout for specific paths

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to create a default configuration that changes the layout of pages under a specific directory using the `path` variable in the `_config.yml` file, that way:

```
collections:
  biterbo-product:
    output: true
  v11-3:
    output: true

...

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "v11-3"
    values:
      layout: "documentation"
      versionDir: "11.3/"
  -
    scope:
      path: "_v11.3/eye-product"
      type: "v11-3"
    values:
      layout: "docueye"
      versionDir: "11.3/"
      mainPage: "eye-product"
```

And my filetree looks like this:

```
_config.yml

_v11-3/eye-product/page-eye1.md

_v11-3/eye-product/page-eye2.md

_v11-3/oculus-product/page-oculus.md
```

So, I want for `_v11-3/eye-product/xxx` pages to have the "docueye" layout while other pages inside `_v11-3/*` have the "documentation" layout. But, it's not working. Instead of that, every page inside `/_v11-3/` have the "documentation" layout, even `/_v11-3/eye-product/*`. Seems that the `path` clause in the defaults is not working.

Every page inside /_v11-3/ has a permalink which is "/11.3/xxx" in their frontmatter. I think this is not important here, but...

I don't know what am I doing wrong, so I would need a little help here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path directive must reference the real directory without initial nor trailing backslashes.

In this example, the path should be `path: "_v11-3/eye-product"`